# Vue owl carousel loop option not work properly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, owl-carousel

i trie to use vue owl carousel on my nuxt project, i've already create plugin on plugins directory , it look like that:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import carousel from 'vue-owl-carousel';
Vue.component('carousel', carousel);
```

and already call this plugin on `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/modules/modules.js', mode: 'client' }]
```

and on my page, i used it like that:

```html
<carousel
  loop="true"
  nav="true"
  item="3"
  dots="false"
  class="owl-guide-slider"
>
  <div class="guide-item">
    <CardGuide /> 
  </div>
  <div class="guide-item">
       <CardGuide /> 
  </div>
  <div class="guide-item">
    <CardGuide /> 
  </div>
  <div class="guide-item">
    <CardGuide /> 
  </div>
  <div class="guide-item">
    <CardGuide /> 
  </div>
  <div class="guide-item">
    <CardGuide /> 
  </div>
</carousel>
```

but this not make the illusion behavior as the doc said like infinite item as it need to do but after reaching the last item it return just to the first item.

Comment: Oh so, you still went owl-carousel. x)

Comment: i just took the more common for me ^^" , haven't tested yet the vue awaesome swiper